# How do I access a counter inside a Ruby iteration?

Tags: ruby, iteration

My google skills are failing me big time. If I have a standary Ruby loop like this:

```
<% @notes.each do |q| %>
<% end>
```

How do I access a loop counter from inside the loop? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `each_with_index` instead of `each` to get the index:

```
@notes.each_with_index do |note, idx|
 p idx
 p note
end
```

Refer to the ruby [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003137) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no loop counter in the example given. In other languages, this style of loop is usually called a `foreach` loop. You can still access the current item of the collection by using the variable `q` in the example given.